# Как создать ХитБокс для 2D игры?

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Я не очень хорошо смыслю в *программировании* и в целом *математике* поскольку недавно начал изучать эту **отрасль**. Мне нужна помощь с разработкой **собственной игры**. Сама игра является 2D. Мне неизвестно как сделать *границы* нужных объектов. Так скажем ***Hitbox***. Сама проблема: описать эти границы объектов в последствии, что бы они могли соприкасаться друг с другом и выполнять определённую часть кода. К примеру нанести урон или остановить движение этих объектов. Прошу объяснить как именно это сделать и как происходит создание **Хитбокса** и как извлекать нужные данные для сравнения "*Прикоснулся ли этот объект с другим объектом или нет?*". Заранее благодарю за советы и помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Это называется коллизией, например можно просто создать класс CollisionRect объекты которого будут принимать x и y и в этом классе будет метод (ColidesWith например) проверяющий столкновение двух объектов по x и y, ширине и высоте объектов. Сложно звучит, но на самом деле очень просто. Я как раз делаю 2D игру на java на libgdx, вот пример кода этого класса CollisionRect:

```
package com.imaginegames.mmgame.tools;

public class CollisionRect {

    float x, y, width, height;

    public CollisionRect(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void move (float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean CollidesWith (CollisionRect rect) {
        return x < rect.x + rect.width && y < rect.y + rect.height && x + width > rect.x && y + height > rect.y;
    }

}
```

А вот уже в процессе игре проверяется на столкновение fireball'a и ракеты которая уничтожает этот фаербол, ракета - bullet:

```
for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
        for (Fireball fireball : fireballs) {
            if (bullet.getCollisionRect().CollidesWith(fireball.getCollisionRect())) {
                fireballs_to_remove.add(fireball);
                bullets_to_remove.add(bullet);
                explosions.add(new Explosion(bullet.x, fireball.x, Bullet.WIDTH, Fireball.WIDTH, bullet.y, fireball.y, Bullet.HEIGHT, Fireball.HEIGHT, 0.5f));
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот на ютубе [ролик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMxtf0sJvr4&t=0s&list=PLrnO5Pu2zAHKAIjRtTLAXtZKMSA6JWnmf&index=12), по libgdx правда, но как видишь в CollisionRect не используются библиотеки libgdx.

Надеюсь помог, если что-то не понимаешь - paint в помощь, просто попробуй нарисовать квадрат первого тела и второго и поймешь что цикл в ColidesWith работает в любом случае, встретились тела 1 и 2 или 2 и 1, и неважно с какой стороны.

И если кратко: границы объекта - это X объекта и X + Width и Y и Y + Height 
Урон - просто если при проверке на соприкосновении двух объектов возвращается true, то параметр например health уменьшается на 20
В общем, посмотри урок, надеюсь ты знаешь английский.